# Configure Linux Distro on Google Dataflow Workers?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, osmium

My Beam/Dataflow pipeline involves some data processing which uses a Linux CLI tool (specifically, `osmium-tool` version >= 1.9.1) which is only available for some newer Ubuntu distros ([cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/utils/osmium-tool) or [disco](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/osmium-tool)). I cannot find any documentation on the OS specs of Dataflow Workers, or if it is configurable.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the goals of the Beam portability effort is to allow customizations such as this.  Though it's still experimental at this point, you can follow the instructions at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/ to completely configure the environment your user code runs in.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the documentation I was looking for!

Comment: Do you have any example modified Dockerfiles that use a newer Ubuntu distro?

Comment: No, I don't have an example modified Dockerfile. You might have to go up to the base images a bit to find where the OS chosen.